# Can I rearrange the values on the X-axis of my column chart?

Tags: column-chart, rstudio-cloud

I am new to coding so, if you have an answer please try to explain it in the simplest way possible. I have my column chart below but I want it to be in order by months (example: ap23_members, apr23_casual, mar23_members, mar23_casual, etc). Is there a code that I can do this or do I need to change the way I have my data entered into the original data frame? TIA

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akLHC.png)